# Stripe Subscription Processing Help - React & Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to process stripe payments through React using Firebase.

I am getting a 500 error on "XXX.cloudfunctions.net/tplannersubscription"
as well as "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'I', "Internal S"... is not valid JSON"

This happens both locally and online.

In the Firebase logs: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'customers')"

I have included all 3 related files below...

Functions:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});

exports.tplannersubscription = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
    
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        // create a stripe customer
    const customer = await this.stripe.customers.create({
        name: request.name,
        email: request.email,
        payment_method: request.paymentMethod,
        invoice_settings: {
          default_payment_method: request.paymentMethod,
        },
      });
  
  
      // get the price id from the front-end
      const priceId = request.priceId;
  
      // create a stripe subscription
      const subscription = await this.stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customer.id,
        items: [{ price: priceId }],
        payment_settings: {
          payment_method_options: {
            card: {
              request_three_d_secure: "any",
            },
          },
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          save_default_payment_method: "on_subscription",
        },
        expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
      });
  
      // return the client secret and subscription id
      return {
        clientSecret: subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.client_secret,
        subscriptionId: subscription.id,
      };
   });

});
```

Sign Up:

```
import React from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";

const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_3T1aZGrzAWtOO19DzSkIRFyI");

const SignUp = () => {
  return  (
    <div className = 'Modal'>
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    </div>
);

}


export default SignUp;
```

CheckoutForm:

```
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CheckoutForm() {
  
  // collect data from the user
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [priceId, setPriceId] = useState("");
  
  // stripe items
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  // main function
  const createSubscription = async () => {
    try {
      
      // create a payment method
      const paymentMethod = await stripe?.createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements?.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          name,
          email,
        },
      });

      // call the backend to create subscription
      const response = await fetch("https://XXX.cloudfunctions.net/tplannersubscription", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          paymentMethod: paymentMethod?.paymentMethod?.id,
          name,
          email,
          priceId
        }),
      }).then((res) => res.json());

      console.log(response);
      
      const confirmPayment = await stripe?.confirmCardPayment(
        response.clientSecret
      );

      if (confirmPayment?.error) {
        alert(confirmPayment.error.message);
      } else {
        alert("Success! Check your email for the invoice.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid gap-4 m-auto">
      <input  // this should not be a text field. maybe a radio button ro something
        placeholder="Price Id"
        type="text"
        value={priceId}
        onChange={(e) => setPriceId(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="Name"
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <input
        placeholder="Email"
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />

      <CardElement />
      <button onClick={createSubscription} disabled={!stripe}>
        Subscribe
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CheckoutForm;
```

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace and where exactly this is happening? what is the steps to reproduce?
Between, you can refer to this complete Stripe&Firebase integration sample:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-payments/functions/src/index.ts